# Make jQuery modal not block other UI elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm using a jQuery modal to simulate a toast message:

```
var modalDiv = $('div.modal');
$(modalDiv).modal({'backdrop': false});
$(modalDiv).modal('show');

runAsync(function() { $(modalDiv).modal('hide'); }, null, 3000);
```

It runs ok and the rest of the UI is visible (since I set backdrop to false), however the rest of the screen isn't clickable.

If I inspect the HTML, I can see that the `<div class="modal fade in">` node is covering the whole screen and is above the rest.

Is there any way to change this, and let me interact with the UI without clearing the modal?

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6z42mw13/2/

Comment: Can you provide a link?  Without seeing it I would guess that you could mess around with your z-indexes and fix the problem.

Comment: Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/6z42mw13/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am not exactly sure what you want to accomplish, but this solution will center the modal on the screen and make your items selectable.

Change the modal CSS to this..

```
.modal {
   width: 200px;
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   right: 50%;
   bottom: 0;
   left: auto;
   z-index: 1050;
   display: none;
   overflow: hidden;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   outline: 0;
   height: 80px;
   margin-right: -100px;
}
```

Your problem is the invisible modal is still there and covering the entire screen, this would fix that.

Comment: I can't tell from that screenshot what is going on.  But the solution I gave you should give the modal a fixed width and height and center it in the viewport, you may need to adjust those numbers depending on your needs.

The screenshot provided gives me no details to what your issue is.  Did you take a look at my fiddle to see how my solution is working?